# Issue when use LineRenderer to draw custom shape in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, drawing, line, shapes, renderer

I want to create custom shape to use in my tetris game using Unity. But here is the issue when I try to use `LineRenderer`.

[image: Here is the picture]

How can I solve it? Is there alternative way to draw line?

[Here is What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xVFl.png) (Sor, can't attach 2 images due my rep too low )

Comment: Why would you use LineRenderer in this context? A basic sprite is way much more efficient. But still, you need to show your code. I'm thinking your start and end point are the same, but LineRenderer will place them at the middle of the lines. What you need is your bottom horizontal line to be half of the width shorter.

Comment: Or your top line to be half the width longer

Comment: Thanks for your cmt. I want to draw tetromino (I, T, J, ...) in tetris game and want to draw it to my gameboard (2d array). Which code should I show ?

Comment: "Or your top line to be half the width longer". You mean change the width of line? Because change the width here will affect all line. I try it with no result.

Comment: Tetris only has 7 shapes, so it would be easier to have 7 sprites for full shape and edge shape. I would not recommend LR in this. You could simply use the x position of your moving item and display the edge version of it at the bottom with same x. But for your LR case, if you make your top line half width longer (currentXStartPoint - halfWidth ), it will overlap the square in the corner and close the shape.

Comment: Okey, thank u very much